# How can I correct a "back to application" link of keycloak during login?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak

We have setup keycloak with identity brokering with an AD for SSO. The login itself works fine, but we see the same error as described in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-5179 when logging in on different browser tabs.

The message itself is annoying, but not a real problem. What I really dislike is that the link "back to aplication" doesn't point back to the application, but to the broker login service (server.com/auth/realms/mf/broker/dbwebsso/login). Thus, the user lands on the same page without getting any further. :-(

Is there a way to either correct the link to the correct starting point of our application or disable the link itself completely?

Thank you
Sven

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Keycloak themes and Override the particular **ftl** file as you need.

Or you can override the base theme (not recommended)

Note: If you are extending theme make sure you are selecting the newly created theme under realm settings -> themes

[This Link will help you to Add Custom Theme](https://medium.com/@shivangbhandari/custom-themes-for-keycloak-631bdd3e04e5)